# plot lower-level interactions with predicted values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
sub <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17,18,18,19,19,20,20)
f1 <- c("f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m")
f2 <- c("c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2")
f3 <- c(0.03,0.03,0.49,0.49,0.33,0.33,0.20,0.20,0.13,0.13,0.05,0.05,0.47,0.47,0.30,0.30,0.22,0.22,0.15,0.15, 0.03,0.03,0.49,0.49,0.33,0.33,0.20,0.20,0.13,0.13,0.05,0.05,0.47,0.47,0.30,0.30,0.22,0.22,0.15,0.15)
y <- c(0.9,1,98,96,52,49,44,41,12,19,5,5,89,92,65,56,39,38,35,33, 87,83,5,7,55,58,67,61,70,80,88,90,0.8,0.9,55,52,55,58,70,69)

dat <- data.frame(sub=sub, f1=f1, f2=f2, f3=f3, y=y)

m <- lmer(y ~ f1*f2*f3 + (1|sub), data=dat)
```

Only the `f1*f3` interaction is significant so now I'd like to plot this interaction using the predicted values from model `m`. I tried

```
X <- with(dat, expand.grid(f1=unique(f1), f3=range(f3)))
X$Predicted <- predict(m, newdata=X, re.form=NA)
```

but get an error...

If I add `f2` and plot the results

```
X <- with(dat, expand.grid(f1=unique(f1), f3=range(f3), f2=unique(f2)))
X$Predicted <- predict(m, newdata=X, re.form=NA)
ggplot(X, aes(f3, Predicted)) +  geom_path(aes(color=f2)) + facet_wrap(~f1)
```

I get two slopes in each panel corresponding to the levels of `f2`, but I just want the `f1*f3` interaction from model `m` (without `f2`). Does anybody know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `effects` package is useful:

```
library(effects)
fit <- effect('f1:f3', m)   # add xlevels = 100 for higher resolution CI's
fit_df <- as.data.frame(fit)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(f3, y, color = f1), dat) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(f3, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = f1), fit_df, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(aes(f3, fit, color = f1), fit_df)
```

[image]

The package prints a `NOTE` warning you that the requested term is part of a higher order interaction. Proceed at own risk. I'm pretty sure the confidence intervals here are asymptotic.

Comment: Thanks Axeman, that is what I was looking for. Do you know how the effects package calculate these predictions? I was trying to calculate them manually but my results never match what `effect('f1:f3', m)` produces...

Comment: I averages over any other terms in the model (according to `?effect`). The documentation also says that averaging over higher-order relatives "rarely makes sense". Use at own risk.